# Keyboard layout always resets to US on reboot

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

So, on each reboot my keyboard always resets to US!

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` gives temporary relief.

Is there a way to make it permanent?

I tried:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

This did not work, and on reboot gnome3 was no longer responsive so I am back to gnome classic....

My other grumbles are here: https://plus.google.com/113037534656133512306/posts/iWjU4zzvVdW

Please stop breaking Ubuntu, it used to be great now its as bad as Windows used to be..... which now only costs £70 and is no where near as high maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will help - but resolving keyboard layout issues on Arch Linux the following command always works :

```
setxkbmap gb
```

Replacing `gb` with your preferred keyboard layout, I have never had this issue with ubuntu, or tested this command on ubuntu, but it should work. Let me know :o) :

Comment: Yep that worked see: @@@@@ ££££££ etc etc

Added to my .bashrc and now my keyboard works - many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I've been stuck at the same problem and using

```
setxkbmap gb
```

didn't help because I was getting error:

```
Cannot open display "default display"
```

typing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration -u
```

helped since it give me opportunity to set all options on keyboard language.
I was using Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Server, without any GUI.

Comment: Thanks, this issue was driving me nuts and your second command solved it!